# How exactly 14 days of mandatory quarantine after visiting "red zone" country look like?

Tags: france, covid-19, ukraine

I live & work in France (titre de sejour aka residence permit), and going to visit Ukraine some time soon (I'm Ukrainian). While there won't be any issues with entering Ukraine (because of citizenship), on the way back I'll likely face the "14 days quarantine".

The question - how it looks like? Staying at home or in hospital? Do you get a special mark of "possibly infected" ?

Wasn't able to find clear answer on official French website, so asking here, in case if somebody had similar experience (probably the procedure is more or less the same for all countries in EU)

Comment: "Travellers are asked to show civic responsibility and to follow the health precautions recommended by the authorities"... We all know what that means. The official answer is [here](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000042105897&categorieLien=cid#LEGISCTA000042107796) (in French)

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, if you are allowed in, and depending where you come from you have to stay home for 14 days on an [honor system](https://montreal.consulfrance.org/COVID-19-Restrictions-d-acces-a-la-France-metropolitaine-et-aux-collectivites-d).

All french quotes are from the linked page from the French Consulate in Montréal (Canada).

When coming in, you will have to sign a declaration stating you have no covid symptoms.

"Une déclaration sur l’honneur que vous ne présentez pas de symptômes de la COVID-19"

It also may be possible you are required to be tested either just before traveling in or when arriving (for example at the airport).

"De plus, selon votre lieu de départ, si vous avez plus de 11 ans vous serez soumis à une obligation de test avant d’embarquer ou lors de votre arrivée :"

You will be asked to do a 14 days quarantine at home or other non specified locations )

"Pour les pays qui ne sont pas sur la liste ci-dessus, vous êtes encouragés à effectuer un test PCR préalablement à votre voyage ou à l’aéroport d’arrivée. Dans le cas contraire, vous serez invité à **respecter une quatorzaine chez vous ou dans une structure d’hébergement adapté**."

This says that they expect people to follow rules and guidelines recommendent by the authorities.

"Il est fait appel au civisme et au sens des responsabilités des voyageurs pour mettre en œuvre les précautions sanitaires recommandées par les autorités."